# Should updating one data point at a time or all change the posterior of a normal-inverse-gamma?

Tags: bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior, inverse-gamma-distribution

I have implemented the normal inverse gamma distribution per section 3 of https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf in some code. However, I've noticed something that I didn't expect. The posterior differs depending on how I choose to update.

So, imagine I have data with n=100. If I update the posterior by taking my prior, updating with n=10, using that posterior as my prior, and then continuing that process until I've updated with all of the 100 data points, my variance (i.e. inverse-gamma portion of the distribution) is different than if I just do one update with the entire set of 100 points once.

Am I wrong in thinking that the posterior should be the same independent of how I choose to update? Am I missing something in how the posterior is computed?

Edit: adding the posterior function for the inverse-gamma:

$\sigma^{2}|x \sim Inv-Ga(\alpha + \frac{n}{2}, \beta + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 + \frac{nn_{0}}{2(n + n_{0})}(\bar{x} - \mu_{0})^2)$

Parameter updating:
$NIG(\frac{\nu\mu_{0}+n\bar{x}}{\nu+n}, \nu+n,\alpha + \frac{n}{2}, \beta + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 + \frac{n\nu}{2(n + \nu)}(\bar{x} - \mu_{0})^2)$

Here's our Scala implementation in case anyone is interested: https://github.com/udemy/statistics/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/udemy/statistics/distribution/NormalInverseGamma.scala

Comment: You are not wrong in thinking that the posteriors should be the same; "yesterday's posterior is today's prior" is your guide.   If you want further help, posting the math you used as the basis for your implementation would be the next step.

Comment: Thanks! I added the update function. It's also the same one found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior for unknown mu and variance.

Comment: You also need the update for $\mu$, because after you've updated with, say, 10 observations, and are starting to update with the next 10 observations, $\mu_0$ in the above expression is different; it's not the original $\mu_0$ any more, but instead the posterior mean for $\mu$ from the update you've just completed.

Comment: I don't have the update for the normal readily available. For my use I only need the MLE of the N and IG, and since the MLE of the normal is just the mean and the mean of the updated normal is just a weighted average, that's all I'm using. I can find the full update formula and post it, but the IG update is where I get the counterintuitive results. The MLE of the Normal is the same if I update one at a time or all at once, but the MLE of IG changes depending on how I update.

Comment: But you *are* updating that $\mu_0$ at every step in your repeated-update path to the final procedure?

Comment: Yeah. I added the update for the parameters that I'm using. I guess I can't do LaTeX in a comment. :)

Comment: ... and $n_0$ is updated (by $+10$) after every $10$ observations and $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean of just the $10$ observations?  (Sort of going down the list of places where mistakes might be made...)

Comment: Yeah, so I start with a prior in the form of NIG(mu, n, alpha, beta) and use the update function above. My posterior NIG is different if I provide the 100 units and do one update or if I do 10 units at a time and 10 updates. That is, the first two parameters stay the same $\mu$ & $\nu$, but $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are different.

Comment: You should probably write out the update of each parameter that is updated, e.g., how $\alpha$ is updated ($alpha' \leftarrow \alpha + n/2$), how $\beta$ is updated, how $n_0$ is updated, how $\mu_0$ is updated, ...  That will make it easier to figure out which ones aren't being updated in a way that's consistent between the two procedures.

Comment: $\mu_{0} \leftarrow \frac{\nu\mu_{0}+n\bar{x}}{\nu+n} \\
\nu \leftarrow  \nu+n \\
\alpha \leftarrow \alpha + \frac{n}{2} \\
\beta \leftarrow \beta + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 + \frac{nn_{0}}{2(n + n_{0})}(\bar{x} - \mu_{0})^2$

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I sometimes use $\nu$ and sometimes $n_{0}$. They are the same variable.

Comment: And the updating is all at once, e.g., you don't update $\mu_0$ before updating $\beta$, which depends on $\mu_0$?

Comment: Correct. I've implemented it in Scala such that it takes an immutable NIG object (the prior) and generates a new, immutable NIG object (the posterior) from the parameters of the first NIG object and the likelihood.

Comment: I'll try an experiment of my own tomorrow, that's it for me tonight, I'm afraid!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for thinking about it. I'll see if I can post a straightforward concrete example tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this might be a programming error; I've implemented the updates in R and gotten the expected result.  Perhaps the code below, which I've tried to write for clarity rather than efficiency, when compared with the original Scala code, will help reveal the problem:

```
mu_update <- function(mu, v, x) (mu*v + sum(x)) / (v+length(x))

v_update <- function(v, n) v+n

alpha_update <- function(alpha, n) alpha+n/2

beta_update <- function(beta, v, mu, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  beta + (sum((x-mean(x))^2))/2 + (n*v/(2*(n+v)))*(mu-mean(x))^2  
}

update <- function(parms, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  list(alpha = alpha_update(parms$alpha, n),
       beta = beta_update(parms$beta, parms$v, parms$mu, x),
       mu = mu_update(parms$mu, parms$v, x),
       v = v_update(parms$v, n))
}

x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
parms <- list(alpha=2, beta=2, mu=0, v=2)
parms_2step <- update(update(parms, x1), x2)
parms_1step <- update(parms, c(x1, x2))
```

Executing it and finding the difference of the two parameter lists yields:

```
> unlist(parms_1step) - unlist(parms_2step)
alpha  beta    mu     v 
    0     0     0     0
```

indicating that the two updates generated the same final parameter estimates, as expected / hoped for.

A more extensive test involving 10 updates gives the same result:

```
parms <- list(alpha=2, beta=2, mu=0, v=2)
parms_2step <- parms
x <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
   x[[i]] <- rnorm(10)
   parms_2step <- update(parms_2step, x[[i]])
}
parms_1step <- update(parms, unlist(x))

delta <- unlist(parms_2step) - unlist(parms_1step)
```

gives the following results:

```
> delta
       alpha         beta           mu            v 
0.000000e+00 7.105427e-15 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

which is evidently due to roundoff error.

Also note that Scala, when dividing two integers, rounds down, so you have to make sure that expressions like `n*v/(2*(n+v))` when executed will actually return the correct, floating point, number.

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! This helped confirm a hunch that I had. The likelihood that gave me the inconsistent posteriors was not from a normal distribution. However, when I tested my implementation how you test yours, i.e. by drawing from a normal and updating using those values, I do get consistent posteriors. This makes sense to me. I just need to make sure my likelihoods are in fact drawn from normal distributions. Thanks again! This was very helpful.

Comment: Actually, my hunch was wrong. So, I get differences even using your r code. I don't get them consistently, but I do get them using your code as is if I run it a few times. And, the differences are greater and more likely the fewer draws from the Normal, viz. the smaller n in the update. Does that seem right?

Comment: Huh, I didn't get any.   Let me make some more extensive tests.

Comment: I didn't get any differences that weren't small enough to be attributable to roundoff error even with 10 updates of 10 each (see added code section in the answer above).   Can you give me the parameters you were initializing with as well as the sample sizes you were using?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, I should have paid attention to the magnitude of differences. And your final thought was spot on. I had originally specified $\nu$ as a Long since the size of the sample would always be an integer. The consequence, though, as you rightly pointed out, was that divisions by $\nu$ resulted in rounded numbers. Thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is already pointed out by J. Bowman in his comments, but let me insist upon the fact that you cannot use this posterior today = prior tomorrow when looking solely at the parameter $\sigma^2$ because the integration over the other parameter $\mu$ turns the points of the sample into dependent random variables, which means that the actualisation principle cannot apply as such. More precisely, the distribution of $x_i$ given $x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}$ and $\sigma^2$ is no longer a Normal independent from $x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}$.